# Testing Finite-state machine module in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, test-bench

I have an issue with writing a test bench for the smart-home system (Comfort module).
The comfort module is designed using Finite State Machine.
How I'm supposed to test the cycle of the module.
If the motion_sen is 1, the module should check constantly for temp_sen and lume_sen.
If anyone has any idea how to make it, I'll really appreciate.

```
 `define start 4'd0 
 `define temp_heat 4'd1 
 `define temp_cool 4'd2 
 `define light_bright 4'd3 
 `define light_dim 4'd4 
module comfort (clk,reset,motion_sen,temp_sen,lume_sen,light,heater,cooler,light_high,light_low); 

input  clk,reset,motion_sen;
input [7:0] temp_sen,lume_sen; 
output reg heater,cooler,light_high,light_low,light;

reg [3:0] current_state;
reg [3:0] next_state;
wire clk; 
initial begin 
      current_state=`start;
  next_state= `start;
     heater='b0;
     cooler='b0;
     light_high='b0; 
     light_low='b0; 
     light='b0; 
end 
  always @(posedge clk) 
 current_state=next_state; 
 always @(current_state) 
 begin 
     case(current_state)
     `start: 
     begin 
         heater='b0; 
         cooler='b0; 
         light_high='b0; 
         light_low='b0;light='b0; 
     end 
 `temp_heat: 
     begin 
         if(motion_sen==1)                   
             begin 
                 heater ='b1; 
                 cooler='b0;
                 light='b1;
                 end                    
         else                     
         heater ='b0;
         end 
 `temp_cool:
    begin 
 if(motion_sen==1)                    
      begin 
  cooler ='b1;
      heater ='b0;
  light='b1;
  end                     
 else 
 cooler ='b0;
 end 
 `light_bright:
 begin 
 if(motion_sen==1)                  
 begin 
 light_high ='b1;
 light_low='b0;
 light='b1;
 end           
 else 
     light_high ='b0;
 end       
  `light_dim:
  begin 
  if(motion_sen==1)                
   begin   
 light_low ='b1;
 light_high='b0;
 end             
 else  
 light_low ='b0;
 end 
 endcase 
 end 

always  @(current_state,temp_sen,lume_sen,reset)
 begin 
     if(reset=='b1) 
         next_state=`start;
     else  
         case(current_state)
             `start: 
                 begin 
                     if(temp_sen> 'b00011110)
                         next_state=`temp_cool; 
                     else if(temp_sen< 'b00001111) 
                         next_state=`temp_heat; 
                     else if(lume_sen > 'b00001111) 
                         next_state=`light_dim;
                     else if (lume_sen < 'b00001010)
                         next_state=`light_bright; 
                 end  
             `temp_cool: 
                 begin  
                     if(temp_sen< 'b00001111)
                         next_state=`temp_heat;
                     else if (lume_sen > 'b00001111)
                         next_state=`light_dim;
                     else if(lume_sen < 'b00001010)
                         next_state=`light_bright;
                 end 
             `temp_heat: 
                 begin   
                     if(temp_sen> 'b00011110) 
                         next_state=`temp_cool;
                     else if (lume_sen > 'b00001111)
                         next_state= `light_dim;
                     else if(lume_sen < 'b00001010)
                     next_state= `light_bright; 
                 end  
             `light_dim: 
                 begin 
                     if(lume_sen < 'b00001111)
                         next_state=`light_bright;
                 end 
             `light_bright:
                 begin
                     next_state=`start;
                 end 
             endcase  
         end 
     endmodule
```

Comment: You ask to solve a certain `software` problem for you, but you did not even define it clearly. You can monitor your signals when the value of the motion sensor is set on or off, just use any suitable software technique to do so. What exactlyl is stopping you?  Also, your code example is barely readable because of the formatrting.

Answer (score 1):

Testing, just like good coding is an art. It is not something I would be able to teach/tell you other then

*"practice makes perfect"*.

A procedure is to provide input which should get your FSM in state X and then test if that is the case. The difficult part with that is for the prediction you have to write the equivalent code of the FSM, *without repeating the FSM code.* (That is why ideally you have somebody else e.g. using UVM to test your code).

Try to get a simulator with code coverage which will tell you if you have tested every (corner) case.

---

Having said all that, I think you should first re-visit you current code as the style is rather unorthodox. Here are some issues I have with the current code:

- Improve your formatting: fix the indenting and add empty lines between 'always' sections.
- Use ANSI style port definitions: `( input clk, ... output reg heater... );`
- Try to use less macro's. Use localparam for constants.
- Use all upper case for constants.
- Add indicators e.g. all state constants start with ST_
- Do not use binary numbers for values. 8'd30 says more then 'b00011110
- Your code is **full** of latches. Use default values or assign a value to every variable in every state.
- Do not use `always  @(current_state,temp_sen...` instead use `always_comb` or `always @ *`

There is a big fuss about using 'initial' in RTL code, some say it is fine others says use reset instead (I am in the latter camp). You have a reset signal so I suggest you use that and remove the `initial` section.

One final remark:
Your FSM first checks the temperature and ignores the light status.
Those are normally two independent variables but the way you have written it, your FSM can't deal with all combinations.